# Android work manager invokes worker after 10 minutes when the current worker still running

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have periodic worker, which executes for every 15 min. The worker uploads the data files into server. But, when the current worker taking time to upload and still running, after 10 min, the work manager invokes the worker after 10 min which causing an issues as both of them trying to access the db and overriding each other. Is there any way to stop the worker being invoked after 10 min when current worker is still running.

I am using the 2.3.0-alpha03 version.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: NOTE: Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes. Can't do less than that: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest

Comment: I know. You are right. I don't want to have it less than 15 min. Once it is scheduled, the current worker runs more than 10 min, the android work manager invoking the worker doWork() method again. This is causing an issue as both the worker still running in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried using unique work? They're meant to keep multiple instances of the same work from running simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I have it has unique work only, while the current worker running still after 10 min, the next one enters the doWork() method.

Comment: @Damu You probably need chaining the work. Check this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work

Comment: May provide some of the code? May be can using atomic and queue logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the workers on the same background thread, so the work request gets queued one after the other.

```
WorkManager.initialize(
    context,
    new Configuration.Builder()
        .setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
        .build());
```

You can read more about threading and WorkManager [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/worker)

Comment: I have implemented the same way, but the second worker still enters the doWork() method after 10 min and have the current one which already working gets cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

If constraints prevent the work request from running you should be able to use an equal constraint on the periodic worker, set the equal state to false before the oneTimeWorker runs and true after the work finishes.

```
private boolean RUN_WORKER = true;

Constraints constraints = new Constrains.Builder()
    .equals(RUN_WORKER)
    .build

PeriodicWorkRequest request =
        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(myPeriodicWorker.class, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                  .setConstraints(constraints)
                  .build();

WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
    .enqueue(request);
```

The method that runs OneTimeWorker

```
RUN_WORKER = false;

OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkResquest = 
    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(OneTimeWorker.class)
    .build();


WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(request.getId())
        .observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
              if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  displayMessage("Work finished!")
              }

              RUN_WORKER = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to use PeriodicWorker. Also, the minimum time required for PeriodicWorker is 15 min. interval. 
According to the docs, PeriodicWorker never have state as SUCCEEDED.

Answer (score 0):

The system stops the work and restart it if the execution time is bigger than 10 minutes

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work

To avoid the stop and restart, the worker class has a support for ForegroundAsync services, which have worked for me:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running

Comment: Is not the android work manager restart and stop, it the request is called multiple time.

Comment: @kyorilys my case was also downloading contents for the app and it seems that the request was being called multiple time.

In order to find the problem, I've commented all of the other enqueueUniqueWork and enqueueUniquePeriodicWork, started in debug with breakpoints over all the calls for the requests entering the same class, and in the beginning of my doWork().

When I did that, after the 10min the code wouldn't call any of the enqueues, but enter directly in the doWork() with the WorkerParams having the same data as the first execution. It stopped with the setForegroundAsync() call.